# add getTime from date to another date without time javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to add `getTime` from giving the date to another date format `yyyy-mm-dd` using javascript.

this is my date :

```
var m = new Date(res[i].DATESTART).getTime();
```

add m to another date.

Comment: You mean `var date3 = new Date(date2.getTime()+m)` or `var date3 = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(date2.getTime()-m))`

Comment: Be careful about adding dates together that could be from different timezones.

Comment: If you're going to end up doing a bit of date math and/or formatting in your app, you might consider using a library like moment.js (https://momentjs.com/guides/)

Comment: var ddm = formatDate(monday);
            var dddm = ddm+" 23:59:59"; new Date(dddm);function formatDate(date) {
        var d = new Date(date),
            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + d.getDate(),
            year = d.getFullYear();
    
        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    
        return [year, month, day].join('-');
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ddm = formatDate(monday);
var dddm = ddm+" 23:59:59"; 
var newdate = new Date(dddm);
function formatDate(date) {
        var d = new Date(date),
            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + d.getDate(),
            year = d.getFullYear();

        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

        return [year, month, day].join('-');
    }
```